# ClassNotFoundException when using custom Parcelable

Tags: android

I use a custom Parcelable to carry some data to a BroadcastReceiver. Here is what i do:

I register my intent and set the extra Parcelable on it along with an extra classloader (intent.setExtraClassLoader(..)). Next i schedule the execution of the broadcast via an AlarmManager.

So when the AlarmManager fires it looks at my intent with its parcel which it can not process since it doesn't use the supplied classloader (as it seams).

I think the classloader gets lost when Inten.fillIn copys the intent to a new one (see stack trace).

```
02-21 21:09:25.214: WARN/Intent(52): android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.company.project.MyParcelable
02-21 21:09:25.214: WARN/Intent(52):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:1822)
02-21 21:09:25.214: WARN/Intent(52):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1713)
02-21 21:09:25.214: WARN/Intent(52):     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:1947)
02-21 21:09:25.214: WARN/Intent(52):     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:169)
02-21 21:09:25.214: WARN/Intent(52):     at android.os.Bundle.putAll(Bundle.java:242)
02-21 21:09:25.214: WARN/Intent(52):     at android.content.Intent.fillIn(Intent.java:4530)
02-21 21:09:25.214: WARN/Intent(52):     at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.send(PendingIntentRecord.java:185)
02-21 21:09:25.214: WARN/Intent(52):     at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java:400)
02-21 21:09:25.214: WARN/Intent(52):     at com.android.server.AlarmManagerService$AlarmThread.run(AlarmManagerService.java:636)
```

So is there any way around that problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Seems that you face with the issue described here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6822

There is a workaround described in one of comments under that link: put your custom `Parcelable` into an additional `Bundle`. Due to the fact that `Bundle` internals are not touched until it's needed, such an `Intent` can be delivered to your app, since nobody will try to unmarshal your class outside your app.

```
  Bundle hackBundle = new Bundle();
  hackBundle.put("key", myParcelable);
  intent.putExtra("bundleKey", hackBundle);
```

Comment: There is a 'rule' for the key bundle and the key intent be different?

Comment: For me it doesnt worked. I tried every comment here and in the 6822 android issue thread discussion. There is another WA?

Answer (score 7):

Put `com.company.project.MyParcelable` in the actual application, instead of doing whatever games you are playing with classloaders. Then, it should be available from both the sender and recipient of the `Intent`.

Comment: The AlarmManager is scheduled when a BOOT_COMPLETED action is received. So i don't start the intent in my application.

Is there a better way to handle the situation?

Comment: Oh! I see. I didn't notice that in the stack trace. Off the cuff, it would appear you cannot use a custom `Parcelable` with a `PendingIntent`, which kinda stinks. Rather than use `Parcelable`, you might need to serialize your object some other way (e.g., to a `Bundle`, to a `String`).

Comment: Yeah piping the data through an extra ready object is one way to go. The strange thing though is, that i get the mentioned exception but my data object is actually transfered. So it does work but spills out the exception all the time which is confusing and threatening.

Comment: Hmmmm...you might want to post this as an issue out on http://b.android.com, if there isn't already an issue for it. I can't for the life of me figure out why `PendingIntent` is trying to deserialize your `Parcelable`.

Comment: I had the same issue with a custom Parcelable object. I solved it using another serialization method (XStream), which I now use only for passing objects between activities.

Comment: This is an old Q&A and it helped me out today on Froyo.  Lets hope this got fixed in Gingerbread.

Comment: Did anyone get any further with this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @CommonsWare I think the reason that AlarmManager does this because it wants to copy the Bundle contents while sending and the way you do this with Parceled data is to unparcel it and then re-parcel it. The code that does this is in Intent.fillIn() and is best effort. If it *can* copy the extras it does, otherwise it uses the original extras which is why your data is still delivered safely. The code in Intent.fillIn() notes the way it is doing things may fail, but defers a fix to the future and says ":-("

Answer (score 1):

There is also a bug in Android that can explain this issue in case you try to pass an intent another intent : 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179480&thanks=179480&ts=1436464704