# Send ArrayList<Object> from BroadCastReceiver to Activity

Tags: android, arraylist, broadcastreceiver, android-activity, parcelable

**Scenario:**

- I have an Alarm scheduled to run on a specified amount of time. Each time is executed, my BroadCastReceiver fires.
- In BroadCastReceiver I do all kind of checks and in the end it results a    ArrayList of Notify class
- I display an Notification on the Statusbar
- When the user taps on a Notification, I display an Activity. I need in my Activity, the ArrayList to display it on views.

Here is the sample code:

```
public class ReceiverAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         ArrayList<Notify> notifications = new ArrayList<Notify>();

         //do the checks, for exemplification I add these values
         notifications.add(new Notify("id1","This is very important"));
         notifications.add(new Notify("id2","This is not so important"));
         notifications.add(new Notify("id3","This is way too mimportant"));

         NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         //init some values from notificationManager
         Intent intentNotif = new Intent(context, NotificationViewer.class);
                intentNotif.putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", notifications);
         PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentNotif, 0);


         Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, when);
         notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
         notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
```

And

```
   public class NotificationViewer extends Activity {


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.notification_viewer);

                   ArrayList<Notify> testArrayList = null;

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            testArrayList = b.getParcelableArrayList("list");
        }
    }
```

And

```
public class Notify implements Parcelable {

    public Notify(Parcel in) {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public Notify createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Notify(in);
        }

        public Notify[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Notify[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(id);
        dest.writeString(text);
    }

    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readString();
        text = in.readString();
    }

    public Notify(String id, String text) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
    }

    /** The id. */
    public String id;

    /** Notification text to be displayed. */
    public String text;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

On testArrayList = b.getParcelableArrayList("list"); from NotificatioNActivity I get this error:

> ```
> E/AndroidRuntime(14319): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ```
>
> ComponentInfo{NotificationViewer}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel
>   android.os.Parcel@4050f960: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7602277 at
>   offset 124

As you can see, from qustions from SO I say that I needed to make my object Parcelable. Maybe I did something wrong in there but... I don't know how to fix it. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I can't see the problem from a quick scan. Can you add an if(getIntent().getExtras().contains("list")) { log.v("", "Exists"); } else { log.v("", "Doesn't exist"); } ?

Comment: The example explicitly types the Creator `Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR`. Shouldn't you be doing that, too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `NotificationViewer` activity fetch values like this:

```
ArrayList<Notify> testArrayList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("list");
```

You are putting values using `putParcelableArrayListExtra()`, so you need to get the value with

`getParcelableArrayListExtra()` instead of `getParcelableArrayList()`.

Comment: I have gone thru your code and I have followed the same mechanism of yours and it is working at my end. You need to debug your code carefully at your end as it is working fine at my end. May be there is some other issue.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with how Notify is declared, maybe I am missing something from Parcelable implementation?

Comment: Your parcelable implementation is alright. The code you have posted, it has no issue. May be some other part has the issue.

Comment: Than I can't manage to find the problem. When using it as you said the error is still there:03-13 12:25:48.324: E/AndroidRuntime(15185): Caused by: Unmarshalling unknown type code at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1913) at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2092) at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1536)

Comment: Arghhh... is was a typo in getParcelableArrayListExtra parameter. You are right, it works now as you said it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Combining custom `Parcelable`s and `PendingIntent`s is kind of iffy - but, as luck may have it, `Intent` is `Parcelable`, why not just pass the `Intent` you received as an extra to the `Intent` you are wrapping in the `PendingIntent` - allowing the receiving `Activity` or `Service` to do the processing?

**Edit**: As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2307764/967142) from CW.

**Edit**: Example

Your `ReceiverAlarm` class would work "sort of like this":

```
public class ReceiverAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intentNotif = new Intent(context, NotificationViewer.class);
        intentNotif.putExtra("intent", intent);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentNotif, 0);

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, when);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
}
```

And in the `NotificationViewer` activity:

```
public class NotificationViewer extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        // Fetch the Intent you received in your BroadcastReceiver
        Intent broadcastIntent = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("intent");

        if (broadcastIntent != null) {
            // Do processing previously done in the receiver here 
            // and create your "Notify" objects.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you provide a brief exemplification code ?

Comment: I think I understand now, but what I didn't mention in the question (as I didn't thought it was relevant) in my notification text I display something like "You have 4 notifications" where 4 is the size of the list. This means I can't use it in my Activity as notification is already visible. Thanks for the code, I will keep it for situations that implies it.